# Why is this code throwing EXCEPTION ? I am having problem in deserialization while I was good on serialization

Tags: java, exception, deserialization, classcastexception

```
package desriialization;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Desiarialization0000 implements Serializable{
    /* STEPS OF DESERIALIZATION
     * 1. Your class should implement Serializable interface
           //                   2. add import java.io.Serializable;
           //                   3. FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file path);
           //                   4. ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
           //                   5. objectNam = (Class) in.readObject();
           //                   6. in.close(); fileIn.close();
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        UserDiserialization0001 hi=null;
        FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gaura\\eclipse-workspace\\JAVA_ADVANCED\\gaurav.ser");
        ObjectInputStream oinp=new ObjectInputStream(input);
        hi=(UserDiserialization0001) oinp.readObject();
        oinp.close();
        input.close();
        hi.hello();
        
    }
    public class UserDiserialization0001 implements Serializable {
         String name;
         String pwd;
         public void hello() {
             System.out.println("Hello"+name);
         }
    }

}
```

Exception thrown is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class serialiiization.UserSerialization0001 cannot be cast to class desriialization.Desiarialization0000$UserDiserialization0001 (serialiiization.UserSerialization0001 and desriialization.Desiarialization0000$UserDiserialization0001 are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at desriialization.Desiarialization0000.main(Desiarialization0000.java:21)
```

Comment: You need to use the same class when you read a serialised object as you did when you wrote it. You can't serialise class A and read it as class B, even if they have the same fields.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the exception message, you have changed `UserDiserialization0001` between serializing and deserializing it.

When you serialized the object was an instance of a top level class called:

```
serialiiization.UserSerialization0001
```

You are trying to cast it to:

```
desriialization.Desiarialization0000$UserDiserialization0001
```

That is a *nested* class with a *different* name in a *different* package.

A cast like that won't work.  Different (fully qualified) class names means that the Java types are different.  You can't cast unrelated types in Java.

When an instance is deserialized, it has the same fully qualified class name that it had when it was serialized.

---

<sup>Can I also suggest that you pay attention to your spelling.  You co-workers are liable to throw *house bricks* at you if your Java class and package names are full of careless spelling errors and typos.</sup>